# Way to see all consumers of a Kinesis Stream in AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

Is there any way I can view all the consumers(lambda, firehose, etc.) of the kinesis stream in AWS console page?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the AWS console but in AWS CLI we can run terminal commands by using [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/kinesis/list-stream-consumers.html) aws document.

e.g. `aws kinesis list-stream-consumers --stream-arn arn:aws:kinesis:<region_name>:<account_id>:stream/<stream_name>`